# Fix Parentheses Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, stack, parentheses

Given a string containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', you must make it valid.

This question is different from the Classic LeetCode Problem. This question is basically asking you to make it valid by fixing it.

If I give you a string:
`"{(}("`

You must return me a new string where Parentheses are matched:
`{()}` or `(){}`

This is not like removing Parentheses Problem either. You can add, but you cannot remove.

So, if given `(`, you must return `()`.

Here is my code, but I realize that it doubles the parentheses. I would appreciate it if someone can give a more efficient solution.

```
def parentheses_fix(paran):
    stack = []
    valid = []
    dictionaryOpen = {'(':')','{':'}','[':']'}
    dictionaryClosed = {')':'(', '}':'{', ']':'['}
    for i in range(len(paran)):
        if paran[i] in dictionaryOpen.keys():
                stack.append(paran[i])
                valid.append(paran[i])
        elif paran[i] in dictionaryOpen.values():
            if len(stack) > 0:
                g = stack.pop()
                #closed paranthesis
                valid.append(dictionaryOpen[g])
                valid.append(dictionaryClosed[paran[i]])
                valid.append(paran[i])
            else:
                valid.append(dictionaryClosed[paran[i]])
                valid.append(paran[i])
    for i in range(len(stack)):
        valid.append(dictionaryOpen[stack[-(1+i)]])
    return ''.join(valid)
```

Comment: Is there an associated cost with adding, changing direction, or swapping?

Comment: No you can do it

Comment: Well, for one thing, you only need to add at most one of each type of parenthetical. All the rest, we can arrange arbitrarily since you indicated there's no cost. So just find the parity of each, count each, and arrange them however you like :)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, it doesn't matter for you how many times we change a char direction or swap positions of chars, so this will do the job:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string buildPar(int par){
    if(par == 0) return ""; 
    return "(" + buildPar(par - 1) + ")";
}

string buildCol(int col, int par){
    if(col == 0) return buildPar(par); 
    return "[" + buildCol(col - 1, par) + "]";
}

string buildCha(int cha, int col, int par){
    if(cha == 0) return buildCol(col, par); 
    return "{" + buildCha(cha - 1, col, par) + "}";
}

int main(){
    string pat = "{(}(()][{{]}()}";

    int par = 0, col = 0, cha = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < pat.size(); i++){
        if(pat[i] == '(' || pat[i] == ')') par++; 
        else if(pat[i] == '[' || pat[i] == ']') col++; 
        else cha++; 
    }

    if(par % 2 == 1) par++;
    if(col % 2 == 1) col++;
    if(cha % 2 == 1) cha++;

    string ans = buildCha(cha / 2, col / 2, par / 2);      
   cout<<ans<<endl;      
}
```

The code basically counts all `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{` and `}`. We simply match each pair of the same type. If both are `(` and `(`, suppose we change the direction of one of them. If there is an odd number of a specific type, add one more. Then change position of all of them to match just fine.

```
OUTPUT: {{{[[((()))]]}}}
```